# regex find replace strings starting or beginning with backslash

Tags: bash, sed, regular-expression

I have a compilation album in my music library that has song titles in the form of `ARTIST/ TITLE`, which is making it really difficult to `cp` or `mv` these files because of the slash. So I'd like to rename the files to `Title (Artist)` to make them more manageable (and also so that they are named in a fashion consistent with the rest of my music library). Here's what I have so far:

```
#! /bin/bash

for i in ./*.flac; do
TITLE=`ls "$i" | sed #display string after backslash`
ARTIST=`ls "$i" | sed #display string before backslash`

mv ./"$i" ./"$TITLE ($ARTIST)"

done
```

Also remember that there is a space after the slash in `ARTIST/ TITLE` which might mess things up too.

Comment: The character `/` is called slash, and backslash is in other direction: `\ `. Secondly, what system is that? It is impossible to include `/` in the Linux filename, and most of other unix-like systems as well.

Comment: Linux. To be honest, slash is not in the filename, it's in the music title tag.  I greatly simplified the question to make it less esoteric.  My actual script uses metaflac and sed.

Comment: Changed backslash to slash in question, thanks.

Comment: @curios: So is your question really "How do I split a string into two pieces at a specified substring?"

Comment: I tried to simplify my question too much which I think confused everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is:

I have a bash variable which contains a string; I would like to split it into two pieces, before and after the string `"/ "`.

If so, here is a simple bash-solution:

```
track="Judy Garland/ Somewhere Over the Rainbow"
title="${track#*/ }"
artist="${track%%/ *}"
```

The `#` syntax means "Without the shortest prefix which matches ...". The `%%` syntax means "Without the longest suffix which matches ...". (Similarly, `##` would have been longest prefix, and `%` shortest suffix.) The pattern is an ordinary bash glob (or an extended bash glob if `shopt -s extglob` is in effect). It is *not* a regular expression.

If the pattern doesn't match, the string will be returned unmodified, and you should probably check for that condition, particularly if you are not sure that there will be a space after the slash.

---

By the way, why are you using `ls "$i"`? Surely that is not different from the value of `$i`; you could just as well have used `echo` or a "here-string":

```
sed '# some sed magic' <<<"$i"
```

Comment: This bash-solution worked for me, and was way simpler than the solution I had been imagining. Thank you.